# How to show a URL image on frontend in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, swiftui, emulation

I'm storing my images manually in Firebase with an HTTPS link, but how would I show it on the frontend as an image instead of just the link in String format?

Here's my code so far:

```
Vstack{
 Image(skinproduct.image)
       .resizable()
       .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
       .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import a package by going to file -> add Packages : and the search for the package called SDWebImageSwiftUI.

You will then need to import the package on the top of your view as:

```
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
```

and to call it on the frontend:

```
WebImage(url: URL(string: skinproduct.image))
```